# Minimization problem with latent function and splines

Tags: statistics, optimization, regression, spline

I have a dataset consisting of pairs $(x_i, y_i)$. I want to determine the function $f$, so

$$
f(x)f(y) = 1
$$

with the constraint that $f(x) \leq x$, $f'(x) \geq 0$ and $f''(x) \geq 0$.

I was thinking that using splines in some way while constraining the parameters should let me find $f$ satisfying the constraints but I'm unsure how to define the minimization problem in the context of these splines. Any ideas?

Data is available here:

```
"x" "y"
0.8 1.111
0.76 1.163
0.98 0.92  
0.66 1.316
0.9 1
0.78 1.136
1.031 0.87
1.042 0.86
0.85 1.053
1.087 0.82
0.83 1.075
1.099 0.81
0.93 0.97
0.4 2
0.34 2.273
1.053 0.85
1.075 0.83
1 0.9
0.89 1.01
0.91 0.99
0.92 0.98
0.95 0.95
0.82 1.087
0.86 1.042
0.88 1.02
0.41 1.961
0.72 1.22
0.96 0.94
0.7 1.25
1.02 0.88
1.111 0.8
0.81 1.099
1.136 0.78
0.94 0.96
1.19 0.74
0.31 2.439
0.39 2.041
1.25 0.7
0.99 0.91
0.87 1.031
0.97 0.93
1.064 0.84
0.44 1.852
0.84 1.064
0.38 2.083
1.163 0.76
0.68 1.282
0.42 1.923
0.33 2.326
0.75 1.176
0.62 1.389
0.77 1.149
0.61 1.408
0.74 1.19
0.51 1.639
0.6 1.429
0.58 1.471
1.176 0.75
1.124 0.79
0.5 1.667
1.01 0.89
0.46 1.786
1.205 0.73
0.65 1.333
0.48 1.724
0.55 1.538
0.54 1.563
0.37 2.128
0.79 1.124
0.45 1.818
1.149 0.77
0.73 1.205
0.3 2.5
1.22 0.72
0.28 2.632
0.71 1.235
0.35 2.222
0.64 1.351
0.53 1.587
0.63 1.37
0.36 2.174
0.49 1.695
0.32 2.381
0.56 1.515
0.59 1.449
0.67 1.299
0.43 1.887
0.25 2.857
0.69 1.266
0.47 1.754
0.52 1.613
```

Comment: Am I missing something? If $f(x)f(y) = 1$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ then on the line $x=y$ we have $f(x)^2 = 1$ so that $f(x) = \pm 1$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Lundborg : I deleted my older comment since it became obsolete after the edit. Note that there will be no function satisfying $f(x_i)f(y_i)=1$ and $f(x_i)\leq x_i$ assuming this is also implies $f(y_i)\leq y_i$ if you have the pair $(0.98 0.92)$ because then $f(x_i)f(y_i)\leq x_i y_i =  0,9016$. So I ask: Do you need an exact fitting function? An error minimizing function? Should $f(y_i)\leq y_i$ even hold?

Comment: @Nadiels This is a degenerate solution but more solutions exist.

Comment: @Mefitico I need an error minimizing function, this should be an exact fit but I simply want the best possibile fit. The relation $f(x) \leq x$ is a likely assumption from the data but not a requirement per se. It was mainly an attempt avoid the degeneracy of $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: @Lundborg Is $f(x)f(y)=1$ supposed to hold only when $(x,y)$ belongs to the curve that the data approximately follows?

Comment: @Oppenede Its supposed to hold for all $(x,y)$.

Comment: You can only satisfy $f(x) \leq x$ and $f''(x) \geq 0$ is $f$ is linear with slope 1.

Answer (score 1):

Function $y(x)$ looks monotonical and continued. At the same time, there is a noise due to the discretization. The best approach is the least square method.

$$\color{brown}{\textbf{Linear model}}$$

Let $f(x) = ax+b,$ then should be minimized the function
$$G(a,b)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left((ax_i+b)(ay_i+b)-1\right)^2$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(a^2p_i+abs_i)+b^2-1\right)^2,$$
or
$$G(a,b)= a^2(W_{20}a^2+2W_{11}ab+W_{02}b^2)+2a(b^2-1)(W_{10}a+W_{01}b)+W_{00}(b^2-1)^2,$$
where
$$
p_i=x_iy_i,\quad s_i - x_i +y_i,\\[4pt]
\begin{pmatrix}
W_{00} \\ W_{01} \\ W_{10} \\ W_{02} \\ W_{11} \\ W_{20} 
\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ s_i \\ p_i \\ s_i^2 \\ p_is_i \\ p_i^2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
91\\
189.336\\
78.15834\\
400.527798\\
161.52697\\
67.315936\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Minimizing leads to the solution with the positive $a:$
$$a_0\approx1.069214,\quad b_0\approx 0.006625$$
(see also [Wolram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%2067315936%20a%5E4%20%2B%20323053940%20a%5E3%20b%20%2B%20400527798%20a%5E2%20b%5E2%20%2B%20156316680%20a%5E2%20(b%5E2%20-%201)%20%2B%20378672000%20a%20b%20(b%5E2%20-%201)%20%2B%2091000000%20(b%5E2%20-%201))).

The plot with the values of $\mathbf{\color{lightgreen}{x_i}},$ $\mathbf{\color{blue}{y_i}}$ and $\mathbf{\color{red}{f(x_i)f(y_i)}}$ is shown below. The dotted plots are $f(x_i)$ and $f(y_i).$

[image: Polynomials product]

$$\color{brown}{\textbf{Quadratic model}}$$

Let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c,$ then should be minimized the function
$$G(a,b,c)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left((ax_i^2+bx_i+c)(ay_i^2+by_i+c)-1\right)^2$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left((a^2p_i+abs_i+b^2)p_i+ac(s_i^2-2p_i)+bcs_i+c^2-1)\right)^2$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left((a^2p_i+abs_i+b^2-2ac)p_i+((as_i+b)cs_i+c^2-1))\right)^2$$
$$= a^4W_{40}+2a^3bW_{31}+a^2b^2W_{22}+2(b^2-2ac)(a^2W_{30}+abW_{21})+(b^2-2ac)^2W_{20}$$
$$+2a^2(acW_{22}+bcW_{21}+(c^2-1)W_{20}))$$
$$+2ab(acW_{13}+bcW_{12}+(c^2-1)W_{11}))$$
$$+2(b^2-2ac)(acW_{12}+bcW_{11}+(c^2-1)W_{10}))$$
$$+a^2c^2W_{04}+2abc^2W_{03}+b^2c^2W_{02}+2(c^2-1)(acW_{02}+bcW_{01})+(c^2-1)W_{00},$$
where
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
W_{00} \\ W_{01} \\ W_{02} \\ W_{03} \\ W_{04} \\ W_{10} \\ W_{11} \\ W_{12} \\ W_{13} \\ W_{20} \\ W_{21} \\ W_{22} \\ W_{30} \\ W_{31} \\ W_{40} \\
\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ s_i \\ s_i^2 \\ s_i^3 \\ s_i^4 \\ p_i \\ s_ip_i \\ s_i^2p_i \\ s_i^3p_i \\ p_i^2 \\ s_ip_i^2 \\ s_i^2p_i^2 \\ p_i^3 \\ s_ip_i^3 \\ p_i^4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
91\\
189.336\\
400.527798\\
863.931994\\
1905.452187\\
78.15834\\
161.52697\\
338.997886\\
724.521647\\
67.315936\\
138.255465\\
288.018453\\
58.12748\\
118.699206\\
50.313345\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Minimizing via MathCAD with the initial point 
$$a_1=0,\quad b_1=a_1\approx1.069214,\quad c_1=b_0\approx 0.006625$$
leads to the solution 
$$a_1\approx 0.314097,\quad b_1\approx 0.75514,\quad c_1=0.006678.$$

The plot with the values of $\mathbf{\color{lightgreen}{x_i}},$ $\mathbf{\color{blue}{y_i}}$ and $\mathbf{\color{red}{f(x_i)f(y_i)}}$ is shown below. The dotted plots are $f(x_i)$ and $f(y_i).$ 
The values of the quadratic residuals are $g_0=0.228178$ for linear model and $g_1 = 0.006671$ for the quadratic one.

[image: Polynomials production 2.]

$$\color{brown}{\textbf{Exponential models}}$$

Let $f(x) = e^{h(x)},$ then the condition $f(x)f(y)$ transtorms to 
$$h(x)+h(y)=0.$$
Let $h(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D,$ then can be minimized the function
$$G(a,b)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(A(x_i^3+y_i^3)+B(x_i^2+y_i^2)+C(x_i+y_i)+2D\right)^2$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(As_i^3+Bs_i^2+Cs_i+2D-(3As_i+2B)p_i\right)^2,$$
or
$$G(a,b)= 9a^2W_{22}+12abW_{21}+4b^2W_{20}-2(3a^2W_{14}+5abW_{13}+(2b^2+3ac)W_{12}+(2bc+6ad)W_{11}$$
$$+4bdW_{10}+a^2W_{06}+2abW_{05}+(2ac+b^2)W_{04}+(4ad+2bc)W_{03}+(4bd+c^2)W_{02}+4cdW_{01}+4d^2W_{00},$$
where
$$
p_i=x_iy_i,\quad s_i - x_i +y_i,\\[4pt]
\begin{pmatrix}
W_{00} \\ W_{01} \\ W_{02} \\ W_{03} \\ W_{04} \\ W_{05} \\ W_{06} \\ W_{10} \\ W_{11} \\ W_{12} \\ W_{13} \\ W_{14} \\ W_{20} \\ W_{21} \\ W_{22} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ s_i \\ s_i^2 \\ s_i^3 \\ s_i^4 \\ s_i^5 \\ s_i^6 \\ p_i \\ p_is_i \\ p_is_i^2 \\ p_is_i^3 \\ p_is_i^4 \\ p_i^2 \\ p_i^2s_i \\ p_i^2s_i^2 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
91\\
189.336\\
400.527798\\
863.931994\\
1905.452187\\
4308.022154\\
10003.30059\\
78.15834\\
161.52697\\
338.997886\\
724.521647\\
1581.452913\\
67.315936\\
138.255465\\
288.018453
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Minimizing via MathCAD with the initial point 
$$a_2=b_2=d_2=0,\quad c_2=1$$
leads to the solution 
$$a_2\approx 0.00886,\quad b_2\approx-0.075331,\quad c_2\approx0.241154,\quad d_2\approx
-0.168262.$$

The plot with the values of $\mathbf{\color{lightgreen}{x_i}},$ $\mathbf{\color{blue}{y_i}}$ and $\mathbf{\color{red}{f(x_i)f(y_i)}}$ is shown below. The dotted plots are $f(x_i)$ and $f(y_i).$ 
The values of the quadratic residuals are $g_1 = 0.006671$ for the quadratic model and $g2=0.000016$ for the exponential one.

[image: Polymomial Product exp]

$$\color{brown}{\textbf{Conclusions.}}$$

The most effective model is quadratic one. The linear model has low accuracy, and the exponentional one does not use the negative coefficients.